# hosting apache streampipes on AWS Cloud

Tags: streampipes

How do I host Apache StreamPipes on AWS with custom user authentication using AWS IAM?

I looked upon articles from streampipes, but didnot find any article which illustrates if the toolbox can be hosted on cloud? Yes, there is some information on using Kubernetes Helm.

Answer (score 1):

while custom user authentication using external auth providers is currently not possible with the latest version, we are currently integrating advanced user management in StreamPipes which will also include connection to external authentication providers via OAuth2.
This will probably be available in the next version 0.69.0.